# modelformset repeated my fields and fetching value from my db

Tags: django

I am using django 3 and modelformset,
But I found a wired thing, that the modelformset is repeating my fields and autofilling the value:
models.py

```
class DemoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Demo
        fields = ['title','content','type']

    #def get_absolute_url(self):
    #     return reversed('index')

        widgets ={
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','style':'width:500px;'}),
            'content': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'type': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control','style':'width:300px;'}),
        }

    #labels = {'title': 'Demo Name',"content":"Demo details","type":"Demo type"}

class HostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Host
        fields = ['name','ip','os','method']

        widgets ={
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'ip': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'os': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'method': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control','style':'width:300px;'})
      }


class CredForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Credentials
        fields = ['login_user','keys','port']

        widgets ={
            'login_user': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'keys': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'port': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-c  ontrol'})
        }
```

views.py

```
def cicd(request):
    u_session = request.session['user']
    user = SystemUser.objects.get(username=u_session['name'])
    form1 = DemoForm()

    HostFormSet = modelformset_factory(
        model=Host,
        form=HostForm,
        extra=1
    )

    hostFormSet = HostFormSet()
    CredFormSet=modelformset_factory(
        model=Credentials,
        form=CredForm,
        extra=1

    )

    credFormSet=CredFormSet()

    demo = Demo.objects.all()
    for form in hostFormSet.forms:
        print(form)
    return render(request, "cicd.html", {'user': user,'form1':form1,'hostFormSet':hostFormSet,'credFormSet':credFormSet,'demo':demo})
```

template

```
{% csrf_token %}

{{form1.media}}
{{form1.as_p}}
{{ hostFormSet.as_p }}
{{ credFormSet.as_p }}
```

But the form is rendered like this:

[image]

Which is not horning the extra value and more strange it is autofilling the fileds value fetched from db automatically:

[image]

Please help out, it is very strange!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset) on model formsets:

> By default, when you create a formset from a model, the formset will
> use a queryset that includes all objects in the model (e.g.,
> **Author.objects.all()**). You can override this behavior by using the **queryset** argument

Hence when you don't specify the queryset this automatically gives you all  objects present in the database. You instead want to specify the queryset when creating the formset instance:

```python
def cicd(request):
    u_session = request.session['user']
    user = SystemUser.objects.get(username=u_session['name'])
    form1 = DemoForm()

    HostFormSet = modelformset_factory(
        model=Host,
        form=HostForm,
        extra=1
    )

    hostFormSet = HostFormSet(queryset=Host.objects.none()) # specify queryset here
    CredFormSet=modelformset_factory(
        model=Credentials,
        form=CredForm,
        extra=1

    )

    credFormSet=CredFormSet(queryset=Credentials.objects.none()) # specify queryset here

    demo = Demo.objects.all()
    for form in hostFormSet.forms:
        print(form)
    return render(request, "cicd.html", {'user': user,'form1':form1,'hostFormSet':hostFormSet,'credFormSet':credFormSet,'demo':demo})
```